# Simple flow for OAuth 2.0 + Google Drive + GAE w/ Python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api

I need to authenticate a user with OAuth 2.0 then get access to his Google drive.file all within Google App Engine in Python.

I spend days trying to figuring this out but Google developer page is really bad at explaining things, they expect user to have expert knowledge.

Is there any articles you recommend or I my approaching this wrong. 
**My app basically want to save file(s) on the users Google drive account.**